# Get URL, perform action on URL change and get URL to ParentActivity

Tags: android, url, webview

I'm getting the URL and finishing the activity when the URL is stackoverflow.com. How do I pass this URL to Parent Activity?

```
wvPayment.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: "+String.valueOf(request.getUrl()));
            if(String.valueOf(request.getUrl()).equals("http://stackoverflow.com/")){
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(PaymentActivity.this ,"Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            wvPayment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            wvPayment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this inside a fragment ?

Comment: An activity actually